# How do I enable only new rows in a Ext 4 Grid Panel?

Tags: extjs4, gridpanel

So I have a `ExtJs 4 Grid Panel` that has two columns.

Column **ONE** is a `ComboBox` with a custom renderer

```
Ext.ux.comboBoxRenderer = function(combo) {
    return function(value) {
        var idx = combo.store.find(combo.valueField, value);
        var rec = combo.store.getAt(idx);

        return (rec == null ? '<img src="/js/extjs4/resources/themes/images/default/grid/loading.gif" />' : rec.get(combo.displayField) );
    };
}
```

Column **TWO** is a numeric column

```
{
  allowBlank: false,
  header: 'Time',
  dataIndex: 'tedPaidTime',
  align: 'right',
  field: {
     xtype: 'numberfield',
     allowBlank: false,
     minValue: 0,
     maxValue: 100000
  },
  flex: 0.20,
  selectOnFocus:true
}
```

Now, when I load the `DataStore`, I want the **FIRST** column to be read only.  Which is easy if I set the `ReadOnly` flag.

However, I have a button that adds a **NEW** record to store and I want that new record to NOT have the readonly flag.

So basically, once you change column one and save, you can not alter it.  Only able to alter new records before they are saved.

The business rules here require them to delete the old record if it's incorrect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself.

Basically, I recorded the combo on the `selectionchange` event.
Then, in the `focus` event, I checked to see if it had a required data key from the store.  If not, then I assume a new row and ran the following:

```
focus: function(combo) {
           var cb = combo;
           if(newTEDetailRecord) {
              if(newTEDetailRecord.data["activityKey"] == "") {
                 console.log("newTEDetailRecord", newTEDetailRecord);
                 cb.setEditable(true);
                 cb.setReadOnly(false);
                 cb.focus();
                 cb.selectText();
              } else {
                 cb.setReadOnly(true);
              }
           }
        },
```